# How to get current table id to add to ajax data when initialisation is used for multiple tables?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables, datatables-1.10

I have the following initialisation for multiple tables with the same class but different id attributes:

```
var $table = $('table.jobs');

$table.DataTable({

    ....
    ajax: {
        url: '/my-url',
        dataSrc: function (json) {

            return json.data
        },
        data: function(data) {

            data.table_id = $table.attr('id');
            // gives the same id for all tables

        }
    },
    ...
});
```

Is there a way I can identify which table is sending the ajax request? I'm trying to avoid duplicating the entire initialisation for every table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```
$('.table.jobs').each(function () {
    $('#'+$(this).attr('id')).dataTable({
         url: '/my-url',
    dataSrc: function (json) {

        return json.data
    },
    data: function(data) {

        data.table_id = $table.attr('id');
        // gives the same id for all tables

    }
});
```

Comment: ah, perfect, thank you! I should have thought of that :)