# Datatable & serverside - How to pass different variable to each ajax?

Tags: jquery, datatables-1.10

I have 3 datatable in a single page. All have the same code (same colomns, same ajax call, same PHP serverside code), except that I want to pass different argument on each ajax call.

Each table have a different data-status attribute and this is this attribute I need to pass to ajax, then to server-side.

```html
<table data-status="4" class="ajax-table table table-hover table-condensed table-striped bootstrap-datatable table-bordered">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <!-- ... -->
```

```js
$("#table1").DataTable( {
  dom: "<'tableTools'B><''<'col-md-6'l><'col-md-6'f>r>t<''<'col-md-6'i><'col-md-6'p>>",
  autoWidth: false,
  stateSave: true,
  // paging: true,
  buttons: [
    'copyHtml5',
    'excelHtml5',
    'csvHtml5',
    'pdfHtml5',
    {
      text: 'Reload',
      action: function (e, dt, node, config) {
        dt.ajax.reload();
      }
    }
  ],
  // ...
  processing: true,
  serverSide: true,
  ajax: {
    url : "ajaxCalendarFnc.php", // json datasource
    type: "POST",  // method  , by default get
    data: function (d) {
      d.func = "getReservations";
      d.status = $("#table1").attr("data-status");
      d.ghostonly = false;
    },
```

I have tried multiple solutions like I found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46036269/how-to-get-current-table-id-to-add-to-ajax-data-when-initialisation-is-used-for):

```
$('.table.jobs').each(function() {
  $('#' + $(this).attr('id')).dataTable({
    url: '/my-url',
    dataSrc: function (json) {    
      return json.data
    },
    data: function(data) {
      data.table_id = $table.attr('id');
      // gives the same id for all tables
    }
  });
```

However I can't find a way to do this.

Comment: What is your intention, filter data?

Comment: Yes exactly. Behind there is also a SQL query which is the same except in the where clause. The status is different for all 3.